# Laravel display data from one database table by using the id of that row

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5.1

So I have a table `pages`, that looks like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->integer('category')->unsigned();
]        });

        Schema::table('pages', function($table) {
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('core_users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('category')->references('id')->on('ecommerce_payment_pages_categories')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');

        });
    }


    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('pages');
    }
```

And a table `categories` looking like this:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ecommerce_payment_pages_categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('core_users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('categories');
    }
```

The `pages model` looks like this:

```
class Pages extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'pages';


    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\User");
    }

    protected $fillable = [

    ];

    protected $casts = [

    ];

    public function categories() {
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\Models\Categories");
    }
}
```

And the `categories model` looks like this:

```
class PaymentPagesCategories extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'categories';

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo("\App\User");
    }

    protected $fillable = [

    ];

    protected $casts = [

    ];

    public function pages_categories() {
        return $this->hasMany("\App\Models\\Pages");
    }
}
```

So in my pages table I save in the `column category` the id of the category that the user selects from a dynamic select that echoes the category id as value and category names as options. But I cannot save it as simple string because in another menu the user has the option to delete categories, so I want that when a category gets deleted to get deleted from the category column in the page table as well. Right now I display the data from the database like this:

```
public function getGet()
{
    return response()->json(['success' => true, 'payment_pages' => \Auth::user()->payment_pages()->orderBy('id', 'ASC')->get()]);
}
```

So for the currently authenticated user I display all the data from the page database table.
**Right now after the user selects a category from my select I save on the category colum in pages table the ID of the category. I need to make a query in order to display in a different view in html the corresponding to the category id I saved in pages table**

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to achieve. Would you please explain what you want and what you get instead.

Comment: shouldn't be:

'\App\Models\Pages' ?

Answer (score 0):

Category column in page migration is not set to allow null values.
To allow null values append nullable column modifier to category column.
Rest of the code seems OK.

#### Page Migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('pages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->integer('category')->unsigned()->nullable(); // <= add this modifier
    });

    Schema::table('pages', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('core_users')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('category')->references('id')->on('ecommerce_payment_pages_categories')
            ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('set null');

    });
}
```